# ERROR: EmptyRoom(), NameError: name 'EmptyRoom' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

ERROR:    Line 29, in Map 'empty_room' : 
I have tried rewriting my classes and other small things and have not been able to come up with any solutions. My indentations are correct(or so they seem) on notepad++ they just didn't transfer over very well to SOF. Any troubleshooting is appreciated:) THANK YOU!!

P.S. I am learning on my own with the book 'Learn Python the Hard Way' and I am doing an exercise to make a game similar to zork. Hope this helps.

```
from sys import exit

class Scene(object):
 def enter(self):
    print "This scene is not configured"
    exit(1)


class Engine(object):

 ##calling Engine(x) x is the mapScene
 def __init__(self, mapScene):
    self.mapScene = mapScene

 def play(self):
    currentScene = self.mapScene.openingScene()

    while True:

        print "\n-------------------"
        nextSceneName = currentScene.enter()
        currentScene = self.mapScene.nextScene(nextSceneName)

class Map(object):

 scenes = {
  'empty_room': EmptyRoom(),
  'living_room': LivingRoom(),
  'office': Office(),
  'hallway': Hallway(),
  'kitchen': Kitchen(),
  'master_bedroom': MasterBedroom(),
  'kids_bedroom': KidsBedroom(),
  'attic': Attic()
  }

 ##when calling Map(x) x is the startscene
 def __init__(self, startScene):
    self.startScene = startScene


    ##When calling nextScene(x) x is the sceneName
 def nextScene(self, sceneName):
    return Map.scenes.get(sceneName)


    ##????
 def openingScene(self):
    return self.nextScene(self.startScene)



class EmptyRoom(Scene):
 def enter(self):
    print ""

    action = raw_input("> ")

    if action == "open door":
        return 'living_room'



class LivingRoom(Scene):
 def enter(self):
    print ""

    action = raw_input("> ")

    if action == "kitchen":
        return 'kitchen'

    elif action == "stairs" or "go upstairs":
        print "The steps creek as you ascend to the unknown..."
        print "Are you sure you want to go up here?"
        action = raw_input("> ")

        if action == "yes" or "kinda":
            return 'hallway'

        else:
            return 'living_room'

    elif action == "empty room":
        return 'empty_room'


    else:
        return 'living_room'



class Kitchen(Scene):
 def enter(self):
    print ""

    action = raw_input("> ")

    if action == "office" or "go right":
        return 'office'


    elif action == "living room":
        return 'living_room'

    else:   
        return 'kitchen'


class Office(Scene):
 def enter(self):
    print ""

    action = raw_input("> ")

    if action == "kitchen":
        return 'kitchen'



class MasterBedroom(Scene):
 def enter(self):
    print ""

    action = raw_input("> ")

    if action == "hallway":
        return 'hallway'


class KidsBedroom(Scene):
 def enter(self):
    print ""

    action = raw_input("> ")

    if action == "hallway":
        return 'hallway'


class Hallway(Scene):
 def enter(self):
    print ""

    action = raw_input("> ")

    if action == "downstairs" or "stairs" or "living room":
        return 'living_room'

    elif action == "bedroom" or "master bedroom" or "left":
        return 'master_bedroom'

    elif action == "kids room" or "kids bedroom" or "right":
        return 'kids_bedroom'

    elif action == "pull string":
        print"You have just opened the attic staircase would you like to go up?"
        action = raw_input("> ")

        if action == "yes":
            return 'attic'

        elif action == "no" or "nope":
            return 'hallway'

        else:
            print "I wouldn't have went either\n"
            print "SMASH, the attic door springs shut\n"
            return 'hallway'

    else:
        return 'hallway'


class Attic(Scene):
 def enter(self):
    print ""

    action = raw_input("> ")

    if action == "downstairs" or "hallway":
        return 'hallway'

aMap = Map('empty_room')
aGame = Engine(aMap)
aGame.play()
```

Comment: Names don't exist until they exist.

Answer (score 1):

The class definition should come first before it is used.

```
class EmptyRoom(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        print ""
        action = raw_input("> ")
        if action == "open door":
            return 'living_room'

class Map(object):
    scenes = {
        'empty_room': EmptyRoom(),
        ...
    }
```

Same for `LivingRoom`, `Office`, `Hallway`, `Kitchen`, `MasterBedroom`, `KidsBedroom`, `Attic`.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `scenes` inside `Map` is run when the class is being built, not when you later call the class to instantiate it. At that time, `EmptyRoom` doesn't exist yet - Python works from the top of your code down, so `EmptyRoom` only exists after it has reached the end of the indented block underneath `class EmptyRoom:`. So for this to work, `Map` needs to go *after* all of your other classes rather than before.

Comment: Thank you! I feel so dumb that I didn't know that! Thanks again!!